# Getting a error when trying to alter column as not null in Auzre datawarehouse

Tags: t-sql, azure-synapse

I tried to alter a column from null to not null . I am getting this error.
[image]

I tried to drop the statistics received this message [image].

This is the table info

[image]

What should I do to update this column??

Comment: Please check for the statistics name this way: SELECT s.name AS statistics_name  
FROM sys.stats AS s  
INNER JOIN sys.stats_columns AS sc   
    ON s.object_id = sc.object_id AND s.stats_id = sc.stats_id  
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c   
    ON sc.object_id = c.object_id AND c.column_id = sc.column_id  
WHERE s.object_id = OBJECT_ID('Staging.watermarktable') and c.name = 'watermarkValue'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax is incorrect here if you want to update from NOT NULL to NULL. It has to be as below

```
ALTER TABLE staging.watermarktable ALTER COLUMN watermarkdate datetime NULL ;
```

Below is the approach to delete if you want to convert from NULL to NOT NULL when statistics are enabled

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It's from null to not null. I have updated the post